# Outbound message failure with "Too many requests"

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage

I have an outbound message set up on my Account object.  This replicates the changes to a local store of the data for searching purposes.  This works well.  However a mass update was performed on the Account object and has created ~7,500 outbound messages. These are all trying to be sent at the same time.

The issue is my internal soap endpoint is reporting the following error:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Exception: Too Many Requests a
```

The useless error message is being truncated too short to know what the actual problem is or where the problem is coming from.

I have found a link which helps to "mass delete" items, but i don't really want to delete my Outbound Message: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199395&type=1

Does anybody have any other suggestions?  I could wait 24 hours but each time this spams my internal servers it is causing other services to report the same error message.

Note:  For any salesforce representatives, why won't this area of salesforce be developed?  I see many requests over many years for Outbound Messages to be improved...

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using native Salesforce Outbound Messaging. From the SOAP Developer's Guide, see [StatusCode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_concepts_core_data_objects.htm#i1421192) (begins in middle of page), where near the end you'll find the following:

> **TOO_MANY_APEX_REQUESTS**
>
> Too many Apex requests have been sent. This error is transient. Resend your request after a short wait.

That would seem to be the real status message that's causing the Exception to be thrown that you're receiving.

If you look at the [Apex Governor Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm), there's a limit of 100 web services callouts in a transaction. According to the [SOAP API Call Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apicalls.htm), each create, update and merge request has a limit of 200 records. Other calls have different limits. I'll let you do the math for your particular transaction and number of accounts.

If it's the Mass Update that's causing the outbound messages to be generated and they're part of workflow, I'd recommend you disable the workflow rule whenever you run the Mass Update. If you don't already have it setup this way, you can easily add a custom metadata setting (or custom setting for that matter) that you can add to any/all workflow rules to easily turn them off and on at will.